# Variable in loop doesn't work (C# + Razor)

Tags: c#, razor

### The goal

Create and declare a `originalProductPrice` variable within a `foreach` loop of Razor Engine.

### The problem

Take a look in the following fragment of code:

```
[...]
@foreach (var market in @Model.Markets)
{
    decimal originalProductPrice = Model.ProductsPrices.Find
        (x => (x.productId == product.id) && 
              (x.marketId == market.marketId)).originalProductPrice;

    <p>@originalProductPrice</p>
}
[...]
```

When I run the view that uses this code, the return is:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

But if I execute this (`originalProductPrice` implementation), everything works fine:

```
[...]
<p>
    @Model.ProductsPrices.Find(x => (x.productId == product.id) && 
        (x.marketId == market.marketId)).originalProductPrice
</p>
[...]
```

Someone knows what could be happening?

Comment: Always. Check. For. Null. Ugh.

Comment: Thanks. Thanks. Thanks. Was. My. Bad. The. Variable. Is. A. Lie.

Comment: If you change the name of the local variable, does the problem persist?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis Yes, it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (@Model.Markets != null) {

}
```